# Динамически подключаемые библиотеки (DLL)

Tags: c++, winapi, dll, c++-faq

Как динамически подключить библиотеку DLL на С++?

Answer (score 9):

Воспользуйтесь поиском и найдете ответы. К примеру:

1. [Работа с библиотеками динамической компоновки (DLL)](http://www.codenet.ru/progr/visualc/Using-DLL.php)
2. [Использование DLL в программе на Visual C++](https://rsdn.ru/article/baseserv/dlluse.xml)

### Неявное подключение

> Это наиболее простой метод подключения DLL к программе. Все, что
>   нужно - это передать линкеру имя библиотеки импорта, чтобы он
>   использовал ее в процессе сборки. Сделать это можно различными
>   способами.
>
> Во-первых, можно непосредственно добавить файл MyDll.lib в проект
>   посредством команды **Project->Add to project->Files**... Во-вторых, можно
>   указать имя библиотеки импорта в опциях линкера. Для этого откройте
>   окно настроек проекта (**Project->Settings**...) и добавьте в поле
>   Object/Library modules на вкладке *Link* имя MyDll.lib. Наконец, можно
>   встроить ссылку на библиотеку импорта прямо в исходный код программы.
>   Для этого используется директива #pragma c ключем comment.

```
#pragma comment(lib,"MyDll.lib")
```

### Явное подключение

> При явном подключении DLL программист должен сам позаботиться о загрузке библиотеки перед ее использованием. Для этого используется функция LoadLibrary, которая получает имя библиотеки и возвращает ее дескриптор. Дескриптор необходимо сохранить в переменной, так как он будет использоваться всеми остальными функциями, предназначенными для работы с DLL.

```
HMODULE hLib;
hLib = LoadLibrary("MyDll.dll");
```

Answer (score 2):

Пример -- в эмуляторе я решил вынести функцию отрисовки экрана в отдельную DLL.

Объявления и переменные:

```
typedef void (CALLBACK* RENDER_DRAW_CALLBACK)(const void * pixels, HDC hdcTarget);

HMODULE g_hModuleRender = NULL;
RENDER_DRAW_CALLBACK RenderDrawProc = NULL;
```

В начале работы:

```
g_hModuleRender = ::LoadLibrary(szRenderLibraryName);
if (g_hModuleRender == NULL)
{
    //TODO: Отрабатываем ситуацию "не смогли загрузить DLL", показываем ::GetLastError()
}

RenderDrawProc = (RENDER_DRAW_CALLBACK) ::GetProcAddress(g_hModuleRender, "RenderDraw");
if (RenderDrawProc == NULL)
{
    //TODO: Отрабатываем ситуацию "не смогли получить адрес функции из DLL"
}
```

Собственно отрисовка:

```
void ScreenView_OnDraw(HDC hdc)
{
    if (RenderDrawProc != NULL)
    {
        RenderDrawProc(m_bits, hdc);
    }
}
```

В конце работы:

```
if (g_hModuleRender != NULL)
{
    RenderDrawProc = NULL;
    ::FreeLibrary(g_hModuleRender);
    g_hModuleRender = NULL;
}
```